Changing the color of same eqn in two different slide
I am making a presentation in beamer. Lets say I have written an eqn in orange color in one slide. Transitioning to the next slide with uncover command, I want to change the color of the eqn to blue. Naive uncover of color is not doing this. I tried with the following:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\uncover<1->{Example code}
\uncover<2->{{\tiny
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sigma_H&={\color{green!50!black}\sigma_0}+{\color{red!50!black}\sigma_0\left[a_s \Delta_g^{10}+a_e\left(\Delta_\gamma^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{01}\right)\right]}\\
        &+{\color{teal}\sigma_0\left[a_s^2\Delta_{g}^{20}+a_e^2\left(\Delta_Z^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4 c_w^4}\Delta_\gamma^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4}\Delta_W^{02}+\text{CT}\right)+a_sa_e\left(\Delta_{\gamma}^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{11}\right)\right]}\\
        &+{\only<2->{\color{blue}}{\only<3->{\color{orange!50!black}}\sigma_0\left[a_s^3\Delta_{g}^{30}+a_s^2a_e\left(\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=rectangle, draw=blue!50, rounded corners=5pt, line width=1.1pt, inner sep=5pt] (char) {$\Delta_{\gamma}^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{21}$}}\right)+a_sa_e^2(\text{terms})+a_e^3(\text{terms})\right]}}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Also I tried to that the box appear to the slide 2, but that also does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to load \usepackage{xcolor} in beamer as it will be loaded automatically. Instead of \begin{frame}{Example}, I would use \begin{frame}\frametitle{Example} which is more robust and flexible.

Some notes:

The overlay-specification <3-> means from slide 3 on to the end of the current frame.
\only<specification>{argument} inserts its argument into slides specified by the <specification> and simply drop the argument on other slides. Don't use something like \only<2->{\color{red}}\only<1->{\color{blue}} text since the effect of \color{red} is overwitten by \color{blue}.

Use \only instead of \uncover:
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
Example code
{\tiny
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sigma_H
        & = {\color{green!50!black}\sigma_0}+{\color{red!50!black}\sigma_0\left[a_s \Delta_g^{10}+a_e\left(\Delta_\gamma^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{01}\right)\right]}\\
        & + {\color{teal}\sigma_0\left[a_s^2\Delta_{g}^{20}+a_e^2\left(\Delta_Z^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4 c_w^4}\Delta_\gamma^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4}\Delta_W^{02}+\text{CT}\right)+a_sa_e\left(\Delta_{\gamma}^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{11}\right)\right]}\\
        & + {\only<2>{\color{blue}}\only<1>{\color{orange!50!black}}\sigma_0\left[a_s^3\Delta_{g}^{30}+a_s^2a_e\left(\Delta_{\gamma}^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{21}\right)+a_sa_e^2(\text{terms})+a_e^3(\text{terms})\right]}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



What's your desired effect for the color of the boxed contents and the box's frame?

For the box, in the first slide, there should not be any box. Now when I go to the second slide, the box will be uncovered around some terms in the eqn.

But in your updated code you didn't use any tikz node box at all. Please make your code and your request consistent.

edited accordingly

Please edit your code, not mine. :-)


for replacing one colour with another colour, you could use the \alt macro

if you need to change the visibility or colour of your tikz box, you can use the the overlay-beamer-styles library. For example if you want to first show the equation and then add a frame around it, you could do draw on=<3-> etc.



\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
Example code
\uncover<2->{{\tiny
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sigma_H&={\color{green!50!black}\sigma_0}+{\color{red!50!black}\sigma_0\left[a_s \Delta_g^{10}+a_e\left(\Delta_\gamma^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{01}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{01}\right)\right]}\\
        &+{\color{teal}\sigma_0\left[a_s^2\Delta_{g}^{20}+a_e^2\left(\Delta_Z^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4 c_w^4}\Delta_\gamma^{02}+\frac{1}{s_w^4}\Delta_W^{02}+\text{CT}\right)+a_sa_e\left(\Delta_{\gamma}^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{11}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{11}\right)\right]}\\
        &+{
          \alt<3->{\color{blue}}{\color{orange!50!black}}
          \sigma_0\left[a_s^3\Delta_{g}^{30}+a_s^2a_e\left(
          \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[
              shape=rectangle, 
              draw, 
              rounded corners=5pt, 
              line width=1.1pt, 
              inner sep=5pt,
              draw on=<3->
            ] (char) {
              $\Delta_{\gamma}^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2 c_w^2}\Delta_Z^{21}+\frac{1}{s_w^2}\Delta_W^{21}$
            }
          }
          \right)+a_sa_e^2(\text{terms})+a_e^3(\text{terms})\right]
        }
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


